# Javascript: A wrapper class (in ES5)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

Right now I have about 3 seperate javascript "classes". I call them like this;

```
ajax(parameters).success().error()
getElement('selector').height(400).width(400).remove();
customAlert({object with arguments});
```

This not only feels like random function calling, but will be likely to give me some naming issues.
Then I thought: How does `jQuery` do it?
Well, I have no idea. I've tried googling the subject but so far I haven't found any results of how to make this happen. Only results of how to add prototypes and such...

The basic idea of my classes is like this:

```
var getElement = function(selector){
  if(!(this instanceof getElement))
  {
      return new getElement(selector);
  }

  //Do element getting

  return this;
};

getElement.prototype = {
  name: function,
  name: function,
  //etc.
};
```

Now, this is kind of working perfectly fine, but I'd like to "prefix" and scope my functions within a wrapper class. I want to call my functions like this:

```
wrap.getElement(selector);
wrap.ajax(parameters).success().error();
wrap.customAlert({object with arguments});
```

However, whenever I try it, I bump into at least one kind of error or issue, like;

- losing the `this` scope within my classes
- Being unable to add `prototype` functions to my classes
- The entire wrapper class reinstantiating with every function call
- being unable to create `new object()` because the scope isn't right anymore

Also, if at all possible I would like to *not re-initialize* the wrapper class every time. (seems wildly inefficient, right?)

So I'd want 1 instance of the wrapper class, while the classes within it get their new instances and just do their thing. Is this even possible or am I just dreaming here?

This is the way I've tried it so far;

```
//It would probably be easier to use an object here, but I want it to
//default to wrap.getElement(selector) when it's just wrap(selector),
//without re-instantiating the old class
var wrap = function(selector){
  //Check if docready and such here
}

wrap.prototype.getElement = function(){
 // the getElement class here
}
//This is where it starts going wrong. I can't seem to re-add the prototypes 
//back to the getElement class this way.
wrap.getElement.prototype = {
  name:function,
  name:function,
  //etc
}
//I can call wrap().getElement(); now, but not the prototypes of 
  getElement().
//Also, I still have wrap() while I'd want wrap.getElement.
```

Then I "solved" the issue of having to do `wrap()` by putting it into a variable first.

```
var test = new wrap();
test.getElement(selector); // works and only inits once!
//However, I did have to remove the 'new instance' from my getElement()
```

I have also tried it this way, but this just gave me errors on top of errors of which I didn't really know why;

```
(function(wrap) {
  console.log("init")
  this.getElement = function() {
    return "test";
  };
})(wrap);
// Gives me "wrap is undefined" etc.
```

And last but not least, I have tried it this way;

```
var wrap = new function() {
  return this;
};

wrap.getElement = function(){};
//This works perfectly fine
wrap.getElement.prototype.css = function(){};
//This will cause "getElement.css is not a function"
```

So yeah, I'm kind of stuck here. There are many ways to get past this in ES6, I've found. I am however not willing to move to ES6 yet (Because I don't use anything that still needs an interpreter). So it has to be ES5.

Comment: *I bump into at least one kind of error* - which are?.. It's unclear why `wrap` should be a class. Couldn't it just be a function? `function wrap(..) { return getElement(...) }; wrap.getElement = getElement; ...`

Comment: @estus I have put the errors in the comments at the last examples, so they are there... As is also visible in my example. I did try to make it a function (within a var), but then I ran into trouble adding prototypes to `getElement`. 
Also, how would I return getElement correctly? -- Would this also not still cause scoping issues? And how would I add other classes? - You may be completely right, but in that case I'm obviously not understanding it very well. Could you provide an example?

Comment: @estus I have just attempted to try this. It resulted in me losing my `this` scope within my `getElement()` class. This way only seems to work (unless I'm doing something wrong) if all I do is returning  `getElement()`, which would make it impossible for me to add any other classes.

Comment: Considering that getElement, etc look like you posted in snippet 1, the thing I've suggested above should work as expected. *It resulted in me losing my this scope within my getElement* - it surely does, because `this === wrap` for `wrap.getElement()`. But `if(!(this instanceof getElement))` line is there exactly to address this, isn't it?

Comment: @estus no, that line had to be deleted as it cause a "cannot get instance of undefined" error. By changing it I got some error stating something about  "right-hand".

Comment: It's impossible if you're using snippet 1 as is, getElement is not undefined at the moment when getElement function runs. The code you're running differs from the one you've posted. Please, provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that shows all your current attempt, it's necessary for code-related questions. If these are multiple JS files, consider providing full listing for them AND the order in which they executed (i.e. html page). A plunk/fiddle could help with that.

Comment: @estus My code differed from the post because I was trying out your example-less method. You could have answered with an example and then maybe I would've seen what I had done wrong. I have posted 3 different attempts in my answer, I think that should suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to wrap your modules in a namespace and keep the classes intact is to use the "Revealing module pattern".

It uses an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE) to set up all the functions with a private scope and then returns just the functions in a new object (which works as a namespace for your module)

```
var wrap = (function() {
  function getElement() {...}
  function moreFunctions() {...}
  function etcFuncitons() {...}

  return {
    getElement: getElement,
    moreFunctions: moreFunctions,
    etcFuncitons: etcFuncitons
 };
})();
```

To answer your second question

> I would like to be able to call wrap() by itself as well. I want it to forward automatically to getElement(). Is this hard to do? Is this possible with this construction? Because this looks very easy to maintain and I'd love to keep it like your answer. - Right now it will reply wrap() is not a function

I haven't tested this but you should be able to attach the functions directly to a returned wrapper function. This should avoid the issue of shared `this` by adding them to the prototype

```
var wrap = (function() {
  function getElement() {...}
  function moreFunctions() {...}
  function etcFuncitons() {...}

  function wrap(selector) {
    return new getElement(selector);
  }
  wrap.getElement = getElement;
  wrap.moreFunctions = moreFunctions;
  wrap.etcFuncitons = etcFuncitons;

  return wrap;
 };
})();
```

This works because everything is an object in javascript, even functions haha

Comment: Oh my god this actually seems to work. Who would've thought it would be so easy?! I'm going to test this out fully right now. (With multiple classes and functions) but I do have one question; is there any specific reason to use `function getElement()` over `var getElement = function(){}` ? Does it even matter, anyway? Just curious.

Comment: Main difference is hoisting, so doesn't really matter. You can even define start the return at the top and define everything inside the returned object! I just prefer the style I posted

Comment: that's awesome, thanks! I have one more question; I would like to be able to call `wrap()` by itself as well. I want it to forward automatically to `getElement()`. Is this hard to do? Is this possible with this construction? Because this looks very easy to maintain and I'd love to keep it like your answer. - Right now it will reply `wrap() is not a function`

Comment: I haven't tested yet but I added a potential solution to the answer

Comment: Oh my god, it works. You are my new hero. If you're ever in the Netherlands, I'm getting you a beer! I have been researching this for hours and hours, and now, thanks to you, it suddenly all makes sense to me. I feel like I've achieved a higher understanding of the subject thanks to you!

Comment: By diving in a bit deeper, I just found out I can split my classes off (outside of the `wrap()` and then add them in a modular way. `wrap.newModule = newmodule`. Which is... well, amazing. (I have some heavier modules which don't need to be loaded all the time). However, now I'm wondering; Is that seen as good/bad practice? I was thinking it's nice to split up the modules (like getElement and Ajax), but is there a reason I shouldn't do it, you think?

Comment: Go for it, doing that is basically the pattern that jQuery utilities use. jQuery utilities are the ones that go `$.util()`. jQuery plugins that are called on jQuery objects are attached directly to the prototype